# R, count non-missing dates in dataframe, return count as column

Tags: r, date

I have this data:

```
Times<-structure(list(record_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Date1 = structure(c(17385, 
17959, 17267, 17204, 17063, 18436), class = "Date"), Date2 = structure(c(17689, 
18001, NA, 17255, 17076, 18471), class = "Date"), Date3 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 18052, 18499), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And what I'd like to do is count the number of dates in each row that are there (not missing) and return that as a count in a new column.

Like so:
[image]

The actual data frame has many more columns in between each target column, so I'd like to be able to explicitly name the columns I'm counting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your second requirement, but please check if this works for you:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
Times %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Date'), names_to = 'Date') %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% mutate(Count = sum(!is.na(value))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(record_id,Count), names_from = Date, values_from = value )
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   record_id [6]
  record_id Count Date1      Date2      Date3     
      <dbl> <int> <date>     <date>     <date>    
1         1     2 2017-08-07 2018-06-07 NA        
2         2     2 2019-03-04 2019-04-15 NA        
3         3     1 2017-04-11 NA         NA        
4         4     2 2017-02-07 2017-03-30 NA        
5         5     3 2016-09-19 2016-10-02 2019-06-05
6         6     3 2020-06-23 2020-07-28 2020-08-25
```

Comment: Works well enough, all the pertinent columns start with "date_of_surgery_by....."  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `rowSums` you can do -

```
cols <- c('Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3')
Times$Count <- rowSums(!is.na(Times[cols]))
Times

# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  record_id Date1      Date2      Date3      Count
#      <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
#1         1 2017-08-07 2018-06-07 NA             2
#2         2 2019-03-04 2019-04-15 NA             2
#3         3 2017-04-11 NA         NA             1
#4         4 2017-02-07 2017-03-30 NA             2
#5         5 2016-09-19 2016-10-02 2019-06-05     3
#6         6 2020-06-23 2020-07-28 2020-08-25     3
```

---

If the columns have some pattern you can use `dplyr` `select` helper functions.

```
library(dplyr)

Times %>% mutate(Count = rowSums(!is.na(select(., starts_with('Date')))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `rowSums`

```
> Times$Count <- rowSums(!is.na(Times)) - 1

> Times
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  record_id Date1      Date2      Date3      Count
      <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1         1 2017-08-07 2018-06-07 NA             2
2         2 2019-03-04 2019-04-15 NA             2
3         3 2017-04-11 NA         NA             1
4         4 2017-02-07 2017-03-30 NA             2
5         5 2016-09-19 2016-10-02 2019-06-05     3
6         6 2020-06-23 2020-07-28 2020-08-25     3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
Times %>% 
   rowwise %>% 
   mutate(Count = sum(!is.na(c_across(starts_with('Date'))))) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  record_id Date1      Date2      Date3      Count
      <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <int>
1         1 2017-08-07 2018-06-07 NA             2
2         2 2019-03-04 2019-04-15 NA             2
3         3 2017-04-11 NA         NA             1
4         4 2017-02-07 2017-03-30 NA             2
5         5 2016-09-19 2016-10-02 2019-06-05     3
6         6 2020-06-23 2020-07-28 2020-08-25     3
```